# Uninstall an Android app programmatically without prompt interaction?

Tags: java, android, react-native

I'm developing an Android app.

I used the following code to uninstall a specific application.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE); intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:com.example.tharindurasanga.locationtracker"));
startActivity(intent);
```

This code really works fine but not giving what I'm expecting since this is resulting a prompt saying user to confirm the app uninstallation. I need to uninstall the app silently without user confirmation.

Can someone suggest me another method of doing this or help me to remove this prompt?

Comment: Hopefully, that is not possible for ordinary Android apps.

Comment: If you're trying to remotely administer a device, you should be using Android Enterprise instead of this.  If you're doing anything else, the prompt is required.  No random app should have the ability to uninstall another without the user authorizing it to.